# How to have more than one output on iterate tables (modelbuilder)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I'm doing a model in modelbuilder where I have as input 5 excel tables and what I want is to have 5 outputs in the end of the model. How can I do that?

I want to have 5 outputs after Project tool.
The model currently is like this:
[image]

Comment: You technically do have 5 outputs if your iterator finds 5 inputs. You need to make sure you're giving each output a unique name. If you want to do something with those outputs, give this a read http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Examples_of_using_Model_Only_tools_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001m000000/GUID-9F197B15-27F6-46EA-BAC5-7A722C5A3C4E/

Comment: If I use Collect values before Make XY Event Layer, the output enters in Make XY as a precondition, why?
And how can I give each output a unique name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying once you run this model you end up with one table, the last worksheet in your workbook? You need to be using [inline substitution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000005w000000). Use the *Name* variable coming out of the iterator in your output featureclass in the project tool. An example would be c:\temp\myData_%Name%.shp

Comment: Thanks! Now I have 5 outputs.
But I noticed another problem, the attributes tables of all outputs only have values in one column, the other two columns are all at 0 and I don't know why

Comment: I bet that's to do with Excel. Have you gone in and used sensible headers and defined the column types? Try that.